# No puedo instalar bootstrap

Tags: laravel, bootstrap-4

Estoy trabajando en `laravel 6.0` y quiero instalar `bootstrap` con el comando

`$ npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.4`

y me dice en la consola dentro de mi proyecto el mensaje:

> "npm" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o
>   archivo por lotes ejecutable.

Comment: Tienes que tener corriendo node e instalado npm para que funcione https://nodejs.org/es/

Comment: Que sistema operativo estas utilizando?

Comment: El error indica que o no tienes instalado nodejs y por ende npm o no lo tienes dentro de las variables de sistema y por eso el comando no se reconoce

Answer (score 0):

yo e tenido el mismo problema y la verdad termine instalando manual mente.

En mi carpeta : `C:\xampp\htdocs\LaravelProyect\public\vendors\bootstrap` coloque mi bootstrap.

y en mis vistas les invoco asi:

```
<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="{{ asset('vendors/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- Imagenes -->
<link rel="icon" href="{{ asset('images/faviconDC.png') }}" type="image/ico" />
<!-- Bootstrap Jscripts-->
<script src="{{ asset('vendors/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
```

Espero que te sea util